# Comma usage with Provided or Provided that

Tags: punctuation, commas

So I was checking the general usage of commas with conjunctions, and saw the inconsistent case of "**provided**" or "**provided that**". Example:

> 1. You can drive a car provided that you have a valid license.
> 2. You may produce your own version of the form, provided that the content is the same as in the attached template.

Why does one of the sentences get a comma, and the other one doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are clearer when the comma is there, but some style guides allow omitting a comma when the two clauses are short and simple, such as your first example.